# numpy create 3D array from indexed list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, gradient, vtk

I'm using

```
p = VN.vtk_to_numpy(data.GetCellData().GetArray('p'))
```

to read a 3D scalar from a .vtk file written this way :

```
p_x1y1z1 p_x2y1z1 p_x3y1z1 p_x4y1z1 p_x1y2z1 p_x2y2z1 p_x3y2z1 p_x4y2z1
```

and so on, with loops aroud `x`, `y` and `z`.

I'd like to fill a 3D numpy array with these data (it's a regular grid), something like `p(i,j,k)=p_ijk` so I can use the gradient and other operators from the numpy toolbox.

Any ideas?

Regards

Comment: Are there any newline or is the file a giant one-liner ? Is there any header info that gives the size of the grid or do you know it beforehand ?

Comment: There are n lines of 9 elements (I don't know why 9).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your situation correctly, you can just `reshape` it.

```py
In [132]: p = np.array("p_x1y1z1 p_x2y1z1 p_x3y1z1 p_x4y1z1 p_x1y2z1 p_x2y2z1 p_x3y2z1 p_x4y2z1".split())

In [133]: p
Out[133]: 
array(['p_x1y1z1', 'p_x2y1z1', 'p_x3y1z1', 'p_x4y1z1', 'p_x1y2z1', 'p_x2y2z1', 'p_x3y2z1', 'p_x4y2z1'], 
      dtype='|S8')
```

It appears to me that your array is ordered in what numpy calls `'F'` ordering:

```py
In [168]: p.reshape(4, 2, order='F')
Out[168]: 
array([['p_x1y1z1', 'p_x1y2z1'],
       ['p_x2y1z1', 'p_x2y2z1'],
       ['p_x3y1z1', 'p_x3y2z1'],
       ['p_x4y1z1', 'p_x4y2z1']], 
      dtype='|S8')
```

If you have `z` variance, too, simply reshape to three dimensions:

```py
In [169]: q
Out[169]: 
array(['p_x1y1z1', 'p_x2y1z1', 'p_x3y1z1', 'p_x4y1z1', 'p_x1y2z1',
       'p_x2y2z1', 'p_x3y2z1', 'p_x4y2z1', 'p_x1y1z2', 'p_x2y1z2',
       'p_x3y1z2', 'p_x4y1z2', 'p_x1y2z2', 'p_x2y2z2', 'p_x3y2z2',
       'p_x4y2z2', 'p_x1y1z3', 'p_x2y1z3', 'p_x3y1z3', 'p_x4y1z3',
       'p_x1y2z3', 'p_x2y2z3', 'p_x3y2z3', 'p_x4y2z3'], 
      dtype='|S8')

In [170]: q.reshape(4,2,3,order='F')
Out[170]: 
array([[['p_x1y1z1', 'p_x1y1z2', 'p_x1y1z3'],
        ['p_x1y2z1', 'p_x1y2z2', 'p_x1y2z3']],

       [['p_x2y1z1', 'p_x2y1z2', 'p_x2y1z3'],
        ['p_x2y2z1', 'p_x2y2z2', 'p_x2y2z3']],

       [['p_x3y1z1', 'p_x3y1z2', 'p_x3y1z3'],
        ['p_x3y2z1', 'p_x3y2z2', 'p_x3y2z3']],

       [['p_x4y1z1', 'p_x4y1z2', 'p_x4y1z3'],
        ['p_x4y2z1', 'p_x4y2z2', 'p_x4y2z3']]], 
      dtype='|S8')
```

This assumes `x,y,z` should map to `i+1,j+1,k+1`, as seen here:

```py
In [175]: r = q.reshape(4,2,3,order='F')

In [176]: r[0]   #all x==1
Out[176]: 
array([['p_x1y1z1', 'p_x1y1z2', 'p_x1y1z3'],
       ['p_x1y2z1', 'p_x1y2z2', 'p_x1y2z3']], 
      dtype='|S8')

In [177]: r[:,0]  # all y==1
Out[177]: 
array([['p_x1y1z1', 'p_x1y1z2', 'p_x1y1z3'],
       ['p_x2y1z1', 'p_x2y1z2', 'p_x2y1z3'],
       ['p_x3y1z1', 'p_x3y1z2', 'p_x3y1z3'],
       ['p_x4y1z1', 'p_x4y1z2', 'p_x4y1z3']], 
      dtype='|S8')

In [178]: r[:,:,0]  #all z==1
Out[178]: 
array([['p_x1y1z1', 'p_x1y2z1'],
       ['p_x2y1z1', 'p_x2y2z1'],
       ['p_x3y1z1', 'p_x3y2z1'],
       ['p_x4y1z1', 'p_x4y2z1']], 
      dtype='|S8')
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems to be the right thing but I'm not sure the data are correctly imported as numpy arrays as I get :    p = p.split() 
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'split' when I do :
 p = VN.vtk_to_numpy(data.GetCellData().GetArray('p'))
p = p.split()

Comment: Oh you can ignore the first line, I used that to create sample data from your string example.  The `p` you get from your `vtk_to_numpy` is already an array, and that's the one I think you need to reshape. And of course, you shouldn't use `4,2,3` but instead `nx, ny, nz` for whatever the number of `x,y,z` values you have are.

Comment: It was the vtk_to_numpy that looked to behave in a strange way but thanks to you, everything works now. Thank you a lot !